# Can't load OBJ model with textures using expo-three

Tags: react-native, three.js, expo

I'm trying to load OBJ model with MTL and textures using expo-three. The issue is that model is loading without textures and it looks something like this:

[image: loaded OBJ model without textures]

Here's my code for loading OBJ model:

```
import { ExpoWebGLRenderingContext, GLView } from 'expo-gl';
import { Renderer, TextureLoader } from 'expo-three';
import * as React from 'react';
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader';
import {
  AmbientLight,
  Fog,
  GridHelper,
  PerspectiveCamera,
  PointLight,
  Scene,
  SpotLight,
} from 'three';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
import { MTLLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/MTLLoader';

export default function App() {
  let timeout: any;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, []);

  return (
    <GLView
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      onContextCreate={async (gl: ExpoWebGLRenderingContext) => {
        const { drawingBufferWidth: width, drawingBufferHeight: height } = gl;
        const sceneColor = 0x6ad6f0;

        const renderer = new Renderer({ gl });
        renderer.setSize(width, height);
        renderer.setClearColor(sceneColor);

        const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(70, width / height, 0.01, 1000);
        camera.position.set(2, 5, 5);

        const scene = new Scene();
        scene.fog = new Fog(sceneColor, 1, 10000);
        scene.add(new GridHelper(10, 10));

        const ambientLight = new AmbientLight(0x101010);
        scene.add(ambientLight);

        const pointLight = new PointLight(0xffffff, 2, 1000, 1);
        pointLight.position.set(0, 200, 200);
        scene.add(pointLight);

        const spotLight = new SpotLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
        spotLight.position.set(0, 500, 100);
        spotLight.lookAt(scene.position);
        scene.add(spotLight);

        const asset = Asset.fromModule(model['r2-d2.obj']);
        await asset.downloadAsync();

        const materialAsset = Asset.fromModule(model['r2-d2.mtl']);
        await materialAsset.downloadAsync();

        await Asset.loadAsync([
          model['R2D2_Diffuse.jpg'],
          model['R2D2_Illumination.jpg'],
          model['R2D2_Normal.jpg'],
          model['R2D2_Reflection.jpg'],
          model['R2D2_Specular.jpg'],
        ]);

        const objectLoader = new OBJLoader();
        const materialLoader = new MTLLoader();

        materialLoader.setResourcePath('/assets/r2/');
        const material = await materialLoader.loadAsync(materialAsset.uri);
        material.preload();
        objectLoader.setMaterials(material);

        const object = await objectLoader.loadAsync(asset.uri);

        object.scale.set(0.025, 0.025, 0.025);
        scene.add(object);
        camera.lookAt(object.position);

        const render = () => {
          timeout = requestAnimationFrame(render);
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
          gl.endFrameEXP();
        };
        render();
      }}
    />
  );
}

const model = {
  'r2-d2.obj': require('./assets/r2/r2-d2.obj'),
  'r2-d2.mtl': require('./assets/r2/r2-d2.mtl'),
  'R2D2_Diffuse.jpg': require('./assets/r2/R2D2_Diffuse.jpg'),
  'R2D2_Illumination.jpg': require('./assets/r2/R2D2_Illumination.jpg'),
  'R2D2_Normal.jpg': require('./assets/r2/R2D2_Normal.jpg'),
  'R2D2_Reflection.jpg': require('./assets/r2/R2D2_Reflection.jpg'),
  'R2D2_Specular.jpg': require('./assets/r2/R2D2_Specular.jpg'),
};
```

And here's my package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-gl": "^10.1.0",
    "expo-graphics": "^1.1.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~10.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "expo-three": "^5.6.2",
    "expo-three-orbit-controls": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-native-webview": "11.0.0",
    "three": "^0.125.2",
    "expo-file-system": "~9.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "~16.9.8",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And the path to my folder with obj, mtl and othjer files is root/assets/r2
I've also tried to load this using this:

```
const object = await ExpoTHREE.loadAsync(
  [model['r2-d2.obj'], model['r2-d2.mtl']],
  null,
  (name) => model[name],
);
```

That didn't worked too.
I've also tried to load glTF model instead with following:

```
const asset = Asset.fromModule(model['scene.gltf']);
await asset.downloadAsync();

const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
const object = await gltfLoader.loadAsync(asset.uri);
```

That didn't worked too, it gets stuck on the last line and never loads the model.

I'm running this on Android and my Expo SDK is 40.0.0

Comment: Have you considered to use the more modern glTF instead? This makes the loading process easier and more performant. OBJ/MTL is a bit outdated.

Comment: @Mugen87 Yes, I've tried to use glTF instead, but that didn't worked for me too. I've updated the issue with my attempts to load glTF, can you please provide me with some examples of how to load this properly?

Comment: Can you please try to load a `.glb` file instead of `.gltf? It will contain all resources (like textures) in a single archive file.

Comment: @Mugen87 it seems like expo-three does not support <code> .glb </code> files loading, because I'm getting errors every time I want to load it in different ways and I have not found any solutions to that.

Comment: Okay, sorry. Seems somebody with `ExpoTHREE` experience must jump in here^^.